# What is the purpose of & in front of a function name?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know that `&` is used for references and I have seen it used like:

```
$foo = &$bar;
```

or

```
function foo(&$bar) {...}
```

or

```
foreach($array as &$value) {...}
```

And I know what `&` means in above situations.

---

But I saw this function in CodeIgniter:

```
function &get_instance() {
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

I have never seen `&` in front of function name before. What does `&` do in above function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [`returning by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), it simply bounds the return value to the variable which you assign it to. In the manual there is a clear example of it:

```
<?php

    class foo {
        public $value = 42;

        public function &getValue() {
            return $this->value;
        }
    }

    $obj = new foo();
    $myValue = &$obj->getValue(); // $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
    $obj->value = 2;
    echo $myValue;                // prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2.

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel like it is good idea not to use it at all because it can introduce hard to debug problems (may be that's also reason why one doesn't see this used quite often). Thanks

Comment: @Dev01 : just pointing out an important use of the `&` operator in CI : the `get_instance` function. Executing, say, `$CI = get_instance();` would return a brand new instance of MY_Controller (bad idea!) while `$CI = &get_instance();` will return the currently used instance.

Comment: @SolarBear: Ah thanks for clearing the confusion, makes perfect sense now :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj ping ping :)